# how to #include an object on another object that already has this #include? c++/cli

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, command-line-interface

I'm using C ++ / cli, and I have several such problems ..

Form1: has a `#include "UserControl1.h"`

UserControl1: must have a `#include "Formulario1.h"`

reason:

Form1 of the show on UserControl1.
At one point Usercontrol1 have to run a method in Form1, and can not access the Form1 type without using `#include "Formulario1.h"`

I tried this way access Form1

```
(static_cast <FormDICOM ^> (this-> Parent)) -> ControleUC (1, false);
(static_cast <FormDICOM ^> (this-> Parent)) -> ControleUC (2, true);
```

but I get error in UserControl1 that FormDICOM type does not exist.
Dai place the `#include "FormDICOM.h"` but FormDICOM already have `#include "UserControl1.h"` and arises errors!

FormDICOM and UserControl1 are in the same namespace!

Comment: Are you saying that you are having a circular import problem because both UserControl1.h and Formulario1.h include each other?

Comment: Yes! The problem is that I do not know how to do what I have to do, without having to include each other.

I Tried
  #ifndef XDicomUCSelecionarLaudo_H
#define XDicomUCSelecionarLaudo_H
#endif
to see if the compiler stop the errors, but to no avail

Comment: The normal method in C++ is to use [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) and then put the implementation in a `foo.cpp` file. I have no idea if this is still workable with the CLI extensions to C++.

Comment: I see. I particularly had not worked with C / C ++, but with C #. I'll try this way that indicated to me!

Comment: You possibly want to apply the `#ifndef __USERCONTROL` ... `#define` ... `#endif` trick inside `UserControl1.h` as (if I'm reading it right) _that_ is the file that's being included twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Form1: has a #include "UserControl1.h"
>
> UserControl1: must have a #include "Formulario1.h"

place the multiple 'include guard' in each (**and every**) header file.

inside UserControl1.h header file

```
#ifndef USER_CONTROL1_H 
#define USER_CONTROL1_H

#include "Formulario1.h"

 ..... <-- all the rest of the UserControl1.h header file contents
#endif // USER_CONTROL1_H

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
notice all caps and underscores like any #define should be, with 
the  USER_CONTROL1_H strongly related to the name of the header file
Do NOT use leading underscores in the defined name as that
can be mis-interpreted by the compiler 
as the compiler prepends 1 or more underscores
on most all names it keeps in its' symbol table
```

inside the Formulario1.h header file

```
#ifndef FORMULARIO1_H
#define FORMULARIO1_H

#include "UserControl1.h"

---- <-- all the rest of the Formulario1.h header file contents
#endif // FORMULARIO1_H
```